# LM317 output overvoltage protection

Tags: lm317, over-voltage-protection, indicator

I am new to electronic design and have two questions about my circuit.

I know that an LM317 has stable output, but when I tested on a breadboard I found out that when I disconnected RV1, the LM317 output increased to 9 V. I want to prevent output of LM317 from overvoltage, so I used a 3.7 V Zener diode.  I have simulated the below circuit in Proteus and it works fine, but in reality I am not sure.

Second thing is: I want to indicate LM317 output status if is it on (even if it has <1 V in output) or off (0 V or overvoltage happened.) I also have doubts about the performance of this circuit.

The circuit to be controlled by the LM317 is between V OUT and OUT GND, as mentioned in Proteus by text.

[image]

Comment: You can modify the circuit to one where [both ends of the pot are connected](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561923/lm317-potentiometer) so you only get about 1.25V when the wiper loses contact.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to have two separate boards, one is the pot and other is LM317 circuit that they connect to each other with IDC Box connector so if wiper pin lost like all other connections are also lost.

Comment: The same idea can still be applied. Design the circuit so there is a pull-down resistance from the ADJ pin to ground. When the board is disconnected this will result in ~1.25V on the LM317 output. (Which is the LM317's minimum output without a negative supply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To protect against pot wiper disconnection you can add a zener between ADJ and GND. Its voltage should be the max allowed output voltage minus 1.2V.

[image]

To light a LED if a voltage is >1.2V you can use this. The voltage divider makes half the input voltage, and if that's more than 0.6V, the transistor will turn on. It's not very accurate because Vbe is not accurate, but it's simple. For a more accurate option you can use a voltage reference and a comparator, or a TLV431 for example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bobflux, I think it's good solution but what about On status that means how can I indicate LM317 output has 1.25 V> ?, I thought about using LED and Resistor in parallel with output, but I assumed that the LED would not light up because of it needs at least 2.2v forward voltage.