# Shelly Uni IDC with a potentiometer as a garage door open sensor (percentage) - voltage regulator with low current

Tags: voltage-regulator, potentiometer, linear-regulator

first of all, I'd like to mention that I'm not an electronic engineer (done some ESP8266 and Raspberry solutions, but mostly by using ready-made components and shields), so if some info is missing or I messed something up, please let me know.

I have a garage door that is controlled by Somfy GDK 700 (manual: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1466156/Somfy-Gdk-700.html?page=66#manual).

Spec:

[image]

General wiring diagram:

[image]

I've attached Shelly Uni (https://kb.shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/shelly-uni) to it using the below schema:

[image]

This way I know that the door are open or closed (using magnetic contactors) and I can open/close the gate via the Shelly app and Home Assistant.

Shelly Uni has ADC input in range of 0-12V or 0-30V and I'd like to use it to know the gate position.

I'd like to attach a potentiometer with 10 rotations to the shaft that is closing or opening the gate (it needs 6,5 rotations to fully open the gate).

According to the spec, I can connect 24V, 500mA to the door controller, I used a multimeter and the output (pins 1 and 4) has 26.5V, so with Shelly Uni taking less than 1W (about 38mA), I have around 400mA left.

I was searching youtube for schemas, but not sure what to search for, because I don't need a powerful voltage regulator, I need something tiny just to use it with a potentiometer and connect it to Shelly Uni ADC.

I', wondering if I can use LM317LZ (https://www.tme.eu/en/details/lm317lz/regulated-voltage-regulators/stmicroelectronics/) as it can adjust the voltage in a range of 1.2-37V and has a 100mA output current.

Will this scheme be fine:

[image]

(according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDbVwpTMCdc)

I found another one here: [LM317 potentiometer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561923/lm317-potentiometer) (first one), but I'm wondering if this won't be overkill for my needs, do I need capacitors and electrolytic capacitors?).

Other solutions I found suggested using IRFZ44N or TTC5200, but they all have large current output which I don't need.

Question is:
How can I turn 26.5V (400mA) into an output of 1.2-24 V (the range doesn't really matter, because I'll calculate the percentage using Home Assistant)?

I have a 5kohm 10-rotation potentiometer so ideally I'd like to use it.

According to https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/lm317
I should be fine with R1=240ohm and R2 (potentiometer) 5kohm, but as all of this is really new to me I'd like to be sure I'm doing things right.